# Difference in answers while implementing insertion sort

Tags: c, insertion-sort

I tried to implement insertion sort in C using while and for loop as follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a[]={4,7,8,2,16,21,12,3,1};
    int n=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    int j,k,i,x;
    /*for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
         k=a[j];
        for(i=j-1;i>=0 && k<a[i];i--)
                a[i+1]=a[i];
        a[i+1]=k;
    }*/
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        k=a[i];
        j=i-1;
        while(j>=0 && a[j]>k)
        {
            a[j+1]=a[j];
            j=j-1;
        }
        a[j+1]=k;
    }
    printf("The elements of the array are: ");
    for(x=0;x<n;x++)
        printf("%d ", a[x]);
    return 0;
}
```

And it works totally fine. But, When I tried to remove the use of variable 'k'. The answer prints as follows: 
[image]

My latter code as follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a[]={4,7,8,2,16,21,12,3,1};
    int n=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    int j,k,i,x;
    /*for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
         k=a[j];
        for(i=j-1;i>=0 && k<a[i];i--)
                a[i+1]=a[i];
        a[i+1]=k;
    }*/
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        //k=a[i];
        j=i-1;
        while(j>=0 && a[j]>a[i])
        {
            a[j+1]=a[j];
            j=j-1;
        }
        a[j+1]=a[i];
    }
    printf("The elements of the array are: ");
    for(x=0;x<n;x++)
        printf("%d ", a[x]);
    return 0;
}
```

Can somebody explain this?. Does anything changes the value of the variable 'i' during while loop.

Comment: Instead of the image of text, please post the actual text. Makes it easier to read on a mobile phone (for example) and makes it searchable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`k=a[i]` saves the value because the `while` loop

```
while (...) {
   a[j+1] =a[j];
}
```

overwrites `a[i]` at first iteration, because `j` starts at `i-1` so `j+1` is `i` at the first iteration.